# Elasticsearch "certificate has expired" from Kibana Dev Tools

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have an Elasticsearch and Kibana Helm charts deployed on my Kubernetes cluster for a couple of years now, and I've been working with Kibana's Dev Tools to query my Elasticsearch.
Since a few days ago I started to get the following error when running any query from Kibana's Dev Tools:

```
{"statusCode":502,"error":"Bad Gateway","message":"certificate has expired"}
```

But when I try using `curl` command or simply opening the browser and entering my Elasticsearch's url and some uri it works and I get anything I need.
Moreover, when I try to fetch the `/_ssl/certificates` field it says that the certificate's expiry is in about a year so I do get to see that the used certificate is valid, but still for some reason I get 'certificate expired' from the Dev Tools.
Anyone knows if there are other certificates used I should check?

Edit: Adding output of field `/_ssl/certificates`:

```
$ curl -k -u elastic:*** "https://localhost:9200/_ssl/certificates?pretty"

[
  {
    "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt",
    "format" : "PEM",
    "alias" : null,
    "subject_dn" : "CN=***, O=***, L=***, ST=***, C=***",
    "serial_number" : "***",
    "has_private_key" : true,
    "expiry" : "2024-01-19T23:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt",
    "format" : "PEM",
    "alias" : null,
    "subject_dn" : "CN=***, O=***, L=***, ST=***, C=***",
    "serial_number" : "***",
    "has_private_key" : false,
    "expiry" : "2024-01-19T23:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt",
    "format" : "PEM",
    "alias" : null,
    "subject_dn" : "CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "serial_number" : "***",
    "has_private_key" : false,
    "expiry" : "2031-04-13T23:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt",
    "format" : "PEM",
    "alias" : null,
    "subject_dn" : "CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "serial_number" : "***",
    "has_private_key" : false,
    "expiry" : "2031-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Note: Replaced sensitive information with '***'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SSL certificates on one or more nodes have expired. To find that node go to `kibana.yml` and check `elasticsearch.hosts`. Which node Kibana is querying, that node's certificate has expired.

You can renew the certificate with the help of [this](https://medium.com/@musabdogan/how-to-extend-elasticsearch-ssl-certificate-expiry-date-99820ff87615) article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't see 'elasticsearch.hosts' in my kibana.yml at all and in the article you mentioned I see in the end that he verifies the changes by checking the /_ssl/certificates field which is the one I checked that showed me a valid expiry date and if that shows me a valid expiry date I believe I don't want to change that  right?

Comment: If you can't see elasticsearch.hosts in Kibana it means it's set to default `localhost:9200`
Can you share the output of `GET /_ssl/certificates`

Comment: Edited the question to include the output of /_ssl/certificates.